# Where was this photo overlooking a valley taken?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, nature-and-wildlife

[image: picture looking over a valley]

This picture was taken from a group on WhatsApp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Google lens, it's from Rainbow curve overlook in Colorado:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.